# How to get date difference in days in MySql

Tags: mysql, date-difference

In mysql, I have a user table with columns

ban_start_date [datetime]

ban_days [int]

Where this means that the user is banned from `ban_start_date` for another `ban_days` days more. How can I select the user table, but add a new column saying how many days left they are banned?

I know I need to check if NOW() is in between `ban_start_date` and `ban_start_date`+`ban_days`, and if so, get the difference. Something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(banned_users.ban_start_date , INTERVAL banned_users.ban_days DAY), DATE(CURDATE())) AS ban_days_left 
FROM
    users as banned_users
WHERE
    DATE_ADD(banned_users.ban_start_date , INTERVAL banned_users.ban_days DAY) > DATE(CURDATE());
```

Query takes only users who are banned at execution time and then adds the `ban_days` to the `ban_start_date` temporarily producing ***ban-enddate*** (`DATE_ADD(banned_users.ban_start_date , INTERVAL banned_users.ban_days DAY)`). After that `DATEDIFF` is used to count the days between ***ban-enndate*** and today's date, which in fact should result in `ban_days_left`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the ban_end_date instead? If you want you can store the ban_days, but you should not need that value very often.

The nice thing (I think) about storing the bad_end_date is that people who are not banned will have that as a NULL. It is extremely easy to look up this one value and tell the user:

"You are banned until ban_end."

At the start of the day you will have check for people with non-NULL bad_end_date values where ban_end_date < now() and set those to NULL. Easy.